# Allow locally built snapshots to override more recent remote snapshots

Tags: maven-2

We have a large multi-module maven project. With the objective of increasing development productivity, we recently started to deploy snapshots to a remote repository (via central build) and introduced maven profiles that mean users only need to check out and build a sub-set of modules and take snapshots for the rest. We have also set our update policy on remote repositories to 'never', to ensure that it is explicit when we want to update local snapshots. A typical command is thus; mvn -Pref -U clean install.

Now, in the maven reactor, the build for the modules defined in the profile works perfectly, maven using snapshots for their dependencies, including downloading any updated ones from the remote repository (important note; to ensure we have a consistent set of snapshots, our central deploy is of all module snapshots from our project, even if only a couple of them have changed).

The hitch seems to be when maven is then resolving dependencies back to those locally built modules from modules that exist outside the profile - if a snapshot has been deployed remotely since the build of such a module, then maven sees this as a more up to date version and proceeds to download and overwrite the locally built snapshot. This can cause breaks where other modules are expecting the locally changed module.

Basically I would like to have an option like 'use locally built snapshot' within any modules in my profile over any remote snapshot, even though the timestamp indicates that the remote snapshot is more recent.

What have other people done in this scenario?

thanks,

Paul

Comment: `This can cause breaks where other modules are expecting the locally changed module.` If you have locally changed module - just compile it and you will have the newest snapshot in your local repository and it will be used for build. Or I don't understand something?

Comment: That is indeed what I do. The issue seems to arise when say a later module has a dependency on this locally built module. Maven at this point checks to see if a remote snapshot has a later timestamp than this local snapshot and if so downloads and installs that snapshot in my local repository overwriting my locally built module.

Comment: Btw I appreciate that part of this problem is that I am deploying all snapshots in my central build, even if not all of them have changed..I am not really sure how to set up a build / deploy that can intelligently deploy only changed modules

Comment: Hm... the stupidest solution is to build your program with all dependencies. Also, if programmers deployed artifact after commit to vcs you can check commits and recompile only changed modules to your repository. This stupid, obvious and not simple... but it works...

Comment: Yeah, the reason we went to snapshots is to avoid having to build the whole module tree locally - it takes too long. People are aligned to working on say just one set of modules which is a much smaller subset.

Comment: On the deploy, developers don't deploy themselves, we have a central build that picks up svn changes and builds / tests / deploys all modules to nexus. I did consider splitting this into multiple build / deploys (one for each area) but then how do we deal with updates across multiple modules, say as part of a re-factor - I want all changes to be deployed together - btw we use Jenkins for this

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662009/which-jar-ends-up-on-the-classpath-in-a-maven-incremental-build  There seems to be a "published" algorithm somewhere that describes what happens.

Answer (score 7):

If you could update to Maven 3, you could use the `--no-snapshot-updates` command line switch (`-nsu` also works to save typing). There's a bug with that option that's fixed in 3.0.4, so make sure you're using the latest release.

You might also try offline mode, but that will stop ALL update checks until you stop being "offline".  First, do a build to make sure you have all the dependencies downloaded to your local repository. You can then enter offline mode by adding `<offline>true</offline>` to your settings.xml (and switching it to `false` when you're ready to start checking for updates again) or using the `-o` or `--offline` command line switch when doing a build.  This works in Maven 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to prevent unchanged snapshots from being deployed. Deploying a snapshot is basically saying:

> "this is now the latest and greatest snapshot, choose me over older (in
>   the sense of timestamp) snapshots"

I guess you could do some jiggery-pokery to your local snapshots, such as link some script to the `install` phase that sets the snapshot's timestamp meta-data in the far future (so Maven always chooses local over remote snapshot). But that doesn't sound good to me at all!

Snapshot deployments can be triggered by source control commits. Can you do this instead?

Answer (score 0):

Problem what artifacts must be updated and what must not to be updated is a very hard problem not only for maven, but for user too. Maven not an AI. I think you can build your project in offline mode to avoid artifacts downloading (but, sure, artifacts that you want to be updated will be not updated).

3 years ago we tried to **solve** this problem such way: build (your central build) must contain only versions (no snapshots). There - you can be sure that if you build project - it is stable the same code. If you change some artifact you make snapshot of module and when work done you create version and update dependencies. **But**, it leads to another problem: if you don't have large system of automatic tests you can spend a lot of time just to create versions (bug -> fix -> version -> bug -> fix -> version -> etc.).

Today I work in small team and if someone update his part he just said that and everybody who want update - take it - and who not - don't take.

I'm not a guru in such questions. So, I will be glad to hear more simple way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but came across the same problem and solved it by splitting the build into two steps:

1. mvn -U dependency:tree
2. mvn test

The first step does the snapshot update without building anything and runs very fast.

Then the second step is a regular build/test, but WITHOUT updatig snapshots.